# Uncaught TypeError in Firebase OTP Verification: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am working on a simple mobile number and OTP authentication website using Firebase. After clicking the "Send OTP" button, I encounter the following error in the console:

`recaptcha_verifier.ts:116 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings') at new RecaptchaVerifier (recaptcha_verifier.ts:116:39) at sendOTP (firebase-script.js:21:25) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testing.html:20:51)`

I have included the necessary Firebase SDK scripts and followed the documentation, but I am unable to identify the cause of this issue. The error seems to be related to the RecaptchaVerifier, and I suspect there might be an initialization problem.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Firebase OTP Verification</title>
    <!-- Add Firebase SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth-recaptcha-compat.js"></script>

    <!-- Include your separate script -->
    <script src="firebase-script.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>OTP Verification</h1>
    <form id="otpForm">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" required>
        <button type="button" onclick="sendOTP()">Send OTP</button>

        <label for="otp">Enter OTP:</label>
        <input type="text" id="otp" required>
        <button type="button" onclick="verifyOTP()">Verify OTP</button>
    </form>
    <script type="module">
        import { sendOTP } from "./firebase-script.js";
        window.sendOTP = sendOTP;
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import { verifyOTP } from "./firebase-script.js";
        window.verifyOTP = verifyOTP;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my **JavaScript code** (firebase-script.js):

```
// firebase-script.js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC01PgXhZ9-9BP01GTWJSs473fmGz5n7Kk",
    authDomain: "otp-verification-27a65.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "otp-verification-27a65",
    storageBucket: "otp-verification-27a65.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "25699686034",
    appId: "1:25699686034:web:b56ff82c6a8685d57cf84b",
    measurementId: "G-P0YV1RSGXT"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

export function sendOTP() {
    const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
    const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('otpForm');

    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, `+${phoneNumber}`, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            console.log("OTP Sent!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error sending OTP: ", error.message);
        });
}


export function verifyOTP() {
    const otp = document.getElementById('otp').value;
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(otp)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("OTP Verified!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error verifying OTP: ", error.message);
        });
}
```

I have checked the Firebase configuration, Recaptcha script inclusion, and the RecaptchaVerifier initialization, but I cannot pinpoint the issue. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this TypeError would be greatly appreciated.